# Poisson distribution for floating value of mean

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am relatively new to Python and has been using np library. I am facing some problem in generating spikes following a Poisson distribution. You can see the details using the following link.

[Random number generation following a Poisson distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280517/random-number-generation-following-a-poisson-distribution)

The basic problem is that if we use an integer value for mean of Poisson distribution, we get a nice distribution (using code below). However for floating value of mean, we don't get a distribution.

```
spkt= np.random.poisson(5,1000)   # Mean of 5 for 1000 samples
plt.hist(spkt)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The mean of a Poisson distribution can be a float. I tried with several floats and I get an array just as with intergers. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html#numpy.random.poisson

Comment: Updated sampling for small  μ  case

Comment: Are you dealing with Spiking Neural Networks?

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely sample using non-integer mean. Code below samples and computes PMF for Poisson distribution and plots the together, Win 10 x64, Anaconda Python 3.7

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import poisson

μ = 3.5
min = 0
max = 20

spkt = np.random.poisson(μ, 10000)

h, bins = np.histogram(spkt, bins = int(max-min+1), range=(min-0.5,max+0.5))
#print(h)
#print(bins)

mean = np.mean(spkt)
print(f"Mean value {mean} versus mu {μ}")

# Poisson PMF for given mu
x = [k for k in range(min, max+1)]
y = [poisson.pmf(k, μ) for k in range(min, max+1)]

# plot sampled vs computed PMF
plt.hist(spkt, bins = bins, density=True)
plt.plot(x, y, "ro")
plt.title("Poisson")
plt.show()
```

with picture like this

[image]

UPDATE

If you want very small μ sampled, the same code works for me, but it is pretty much zeroes all the way.

```
μ = 2.0e-5
```

output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with Spiking Neural Networks, I strongly advise you to have a look [those packages on python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54189591/1953250). Particularly, I used [brian2](https://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) over a long time in order to implement various SNNs. To point your question with brian2 package:

```
P = PoissonGroup(100, np.arange(100)*Hz + 10*Hz)
```

More details [here](https://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/input.html#poisson-inputs).